# Dynamic donut chart with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to make a donut chart dynamic with your mouse? I haven't found documentation on that in ChartJS. And what are the alternatives if not?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with you want to make it dynamically with your mouse?

Comment: I want to be able to change percentages by using borders on slices with your mouse.